# What is the meaning of doing orthogonal projection?in what situation,we need to project a vector onto another vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

What is the meaning of doing orthogonal projection?

Every website,every teacher will tell the students that if you want to project a vector onto another vector,you can use $proj_vy=\frac{\vec y\cdot \vec v}{|\vec v|^2}\vec v$.

But none of them tell us in what situation,we will need to project a vector onto another vector,can anyone tell me in what situation,we need to project a vector onto another vector?

Comment: For example, determining the distance between two points, a point and a line, a point and a plane, etc.

Comment: @jl00 i think it is not ,because the orthogonal projection seems that trying to  let a vector become another vector size,there is no relation about distance  between two points,or point and a line or point and a plane